# Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I am trying to set up docker swarm with an overlay network. I have some hosts on aws while others are laptops running Ubuntu(same as on aws). Every node has a static public IP. I have created an overlay network as:
`docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable test-net`

I have created a swarm network on one of the aws hosts. Every other node is able to join that swarm network.

However when I run `docker run -it --name alpine2 --network test-net alpine` on any node not on aws, I get the error: `docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.`

But if I run the same on any aws host, then everything is working fine. Is there anything more I need to do in terms of networking/ports If there are some nodes on aws while others are not?

I have opened the ports required for swarm networking on all machines.

**EDIT**: All the nodes are marked as "active" when listing in the manager node.

**UPDATE** Solved this issue by opening the respective ports. It now works if all the nodes are Linux based. But when I try to make a swarm with the manager as Linux(ubuntu) os, mac os machines are not able to join the swarm.

Answer (score 4):

check if the node in drain state:

```
docker node inspect --format {{.Spec.Availability}} node
```

if yes then update the state:

```
docker node update --availability active node
```

here is the explanation:

> Resolution
>
> When a node is in drain state, it is expected behavior that you should
>   not be able to allocate swarm mode resources such as multi-host
>   overlay network IP addresses to the node.However, swarm mode does not
>   currently provide a messaging mechanism between the swarm leader where
>   IP address management occurs back to the worker node that requested
>   the IP address. So docker run fails with context deadline exceeded.
>   Internal engineering issue escalation/292 has been opened to provide a
>   better error message in a future release of the Docker daemon.

[source](https://success.docker.com/article/context-deadline-exceeded-error-observed-while-starting-container-on-drained-node)

Comment: @SwapnilPandey You said that you fixed this issue after opening the ports. However, if the ports are opened and Docker still shows this error, is there anything that I could do? BTW, I have a similar setup to yours.

Comment: @angheladrian are both the machines on the same subnet? I failed to connect two machines on two different subnets and subsequently dropped the idea of using docker swarm.

Comment: @SwapnilPandey what if a node is on Digital Ocean and the other is on GCP? :)

Answer (score 3):

Check if the below ports are opened on both machines.

- **TCP** port `2377`
- **TCP** and **UDP** port `7946`
- **UDP** port `4789`

You may use `ufw` to allow the ports:

```sh
ufw allow 2377/tcp
```

Comment: To test do you need these e.g. on CentOS temporarily disable firewall and selinux. systemctl stop firewalld; setenforcing 0; If you can then docker create containers then re-enable firewazll and selinux and open ports and add exceptions needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, managed to fix it by making sure the **ENGINE VERSION** of the nodes were the same.

```
sudo docker node ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Another common cause for this is Ubuntu server installer installing docker using snap, and that package is buggy. Uninstall with snap and install using apt. And reconsider Ubuntu. :-/

Comment: This was my issue. Removing it from snap and reinstalling with apt solved it.

I am using Ubuntu because it is the distro I am most comfortable with. I know there is more security on other distros, but I simply have a hard time getting around in them and no time to continue digging around to get everything to work.

Comment: @maarten I see your point, but apparently there is more stability on other distros as well. Leaving a broken docker snap-package in an LTS release is unforgivable IMHO. And I've seen similar problems before, with buggy packages in LTS releases and no fix. Debian is similar enough, and my recommendation.