# mounting permission denied in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, permissions, mount

I was facing issues installing docker on cloud server according to the official guide([Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)). I finished old version's uninstallation, the repository setting up and docker engine installation (sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io). However, I got an error when running hello-world.

```
wyf@VM1103-Timi:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"proc\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e9fedf64e8983aa01e513cee591cdfd7fc60962466a476b51fc1ead682ec8022/merged\\\" at \\\"/proc\\\" caused \\\"permission denied\\\"\"": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I tried restart docker and server, but the problem still exists.
So, it would be great if someone can guide me in fixing this error.
Please let me know if you have any idea about this issue.
Thank you very much!

Ps:
My system is Ubuntu 18.04. Thus, I did not have selinux. Instead of selinux, I checked AppArmor log.

```
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi networkd-dispatcher[155]: WARNING:Unknown index 37 seen, reloading interface list
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi systemd-networkd[126]: veth71cf495: Link UP
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi containerd[170]: time="2020-05-19T21:14:55.679793295+08:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/4c207ce1273d2c863ee419c5ebb271163a031394bd4c17ee75d44267d631954d/shim.sock" debug=false pid=106265
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi containerd[170]: time="2020-05-19T21:14:55.767796543+08:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=4c207ce1273d2c863ee419c5ebb271163a031394bd4c17ee75d44267d631954d
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi dockerd[15100]: time="2020-05-19T21:14:55.776863367+08:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi dockerd[15100]: time="2020-05-19T21:14:55.776953910+08:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi systemd-networkd[126]: veth71cf495: Link DOWN
May 19 21:14:55 VM1103-Timi dockerd[15100]: time="2020-05-19T21:14:55.927805156+08:00" level=error msg="4c207ce1273d2c863ee419c5ebb271163a031394bd4c17ee75d44267d631954d cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
```

The strange thing is that there is no record of permission-denied error.

Here are my ubuntu version, kernal version and docker info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

```
5.3.18-3-pve
```

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
Server:
 Containers: 8
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 8
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.3.18-3-pve
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 4GiB
 Name: VM1103-Timi
 ID: 3G3F:LTVZ:NO25:C7LA:XKQV:ETMB:B6QU:3ZFJ:KBA5:R3KK:QZEA:ZONC
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

It seemed that the AppArmor Profile "docker-default" was lost. "docker-default" was not correctly generated. Check as follows:

```
root@VM1103-Timi:/etc/apparmor.d# aa-status
    apparmor module is loaded.
    12 profiles are loaded.
    12 profiles are in enforce mode.
       /sbin/dhclient
       /usr/bin/man
       /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
       /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
       /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
       /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
       /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium
       /usr/sbin/mysqld
       /usr/sbin/tcpdump
       docker-default
       man_filter
       man_groff
    0 profiles are in complain mode.
    1 processes have profiles defined.
    1 processes are in enforce mode.
       /usr/sbin/mysqld (258)
    0 processes are in complain mode.
    0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Comment: Similar problem for me. Docker re-installed/upgraded. Error response from daemon: remount /docker/overlay2/e7..91/merged/host/net, flags: 0x44000: permission denied
ERROR: docker command failed (rc=1, t=600, cmd=-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock cp)
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused "rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting "/proc/1/net" to rootfs "/docker/overlay2/e7..91/merged" at "/docker/overlay2/e7..91/merged/host/net" caused "permission denied: unknown```

Comment: Solution might be to open ports needed. To test: disable selinux and firewalld, e.g. on CentOS systemctl stop firewalld; setenforcing 0; If you can then create containers you can enable firewall and selinux and open ports and add exceptions as needed.

Answer (score -2):

Solution is probably to open ports needed. Your system might be running selinux and (ufw or firewalld or iptables) ?and/or others?. Read up a bit on linux firewall tools, in particular the ones running on your system.

For the selinux case, you need to check selinux logs, is it blocking access? Add exceptions using selinux commands. 
https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux  These tools are well worth learning but can be complicated. A quick test disabling selinux and firewalld can confirm that this is the source of problem and you can enable selinux and firewalld later and allow/open ports in a secure way.

Simple test: disable selinux and firewalld, e.g. on CentOS

```
systemctl stop firewalld;
setenforcing 0;
```

If you can create containers with selinux disabled then you have confirmed selinux is your problem. You can enable firewall and selinux and then add exceptions and open ports as needed later.

This looks good (specific to ubuntu but general enough IMHO), It details ufw commands, firewalld commands and iptables commands needed for opening ports to allow docker swarm to work) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04

I originally got useful info on ufw commands to open ports needed from here:
[Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388405/error-response-from-daemon-attaching-to-network-failed-make-sure-your-network)

```
ufw allow 2376/tcp 
ufw allow 2377/tcp
ufw allow 7946/tcp
ufw allow 7946/udp
ufw allow 4789/udp
ufw enable #maybe
ufw reload
systemctl restart docker
```

This is a common enough problem where something usually selinux is not allowing access to ports needed.
e.g.
https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/333

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried allowing some ports. `ufw allow 2377/tcp
ufw allow 7946/tcp
ufw allow 7946/udp
ufw allow 4789/udp`
But the problem still exists. By the way, since my OS was ubuntu I did not found selinux on it.

Comment: This seems good for ubuntu, (details ufw commands, firewalld commands and iptables commands needed for opening ports, see there is additional ufw allow 2376/tcp and afterwards ufw reload and systemctl restart docker) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: As advised, I opened these ports via ufw. Just like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04). `ufw reload` and `systemctl restart docker`. However, the problem still exists. Are there any useful logs worth checking?

Comment: Hmm. I did `apt-get install docker docker.io`; and `docker run hello-world`; on ubuntu 19.10 and it ran ok. docker info shows swarm is disabled for me. If you run `docker info` do you see Swarm: inactive or Swarm: active ? And if active what does `docker node ls` show ? I am wondering is your swarm initialised ok ?

Comment: I see above in your docker info it shows Swarm: inactive. So that's not it . .

Comment: And I understand now apparmor == selinux but for ubuntu. Ok. I think the errors you show in the apparmor log are your problem. In my syslog when I installed docker I see this: `kernel: [92659.311028] audit: type=1400 audit(1590073583.082:194): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=26483 comm="apparmor_parser"`
`apparmor_status` command shows docker-default profile under the enforce mode list. Does your apparmor_status show a profile for docker ?

Comment: this is interesting: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/ docker should load that docker-default profile for running containers. However another profile for docker engine you have to get and load manually.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you are right. I did not find docker-default in directory `/etc/apparmor.d`. What's more, It seemed that some profiles and processes were missing in enforce mode and complain mode.(Please see my update to the question) I manually created a docker-default file in directory `/etc/apparmor.d`. However, the problem still exists.

Comment: As well as apparmor docker profile I think you need an apparmor docker engine profile. That docs.docker apparmor page stated that.